# What does this mean: unable to find an inherited method for function ‘A’ for signature ‘"B"’

Tags: r

I am new to R and keep getting errors with the following message:

> unable to find an inherited method for function ‘A’ for signature ‘"B"’

In most cases I've been able to solve my issues by finding alternate examples online, but I'd like to understand what the error message means so I can better understand how R works.

For example, this code:

```
library("RSQLite")
con = dbConnect(drv="SQLite", dbname="database.db")
```

Generates this warning:

> unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbConnect’ for signature ‘"character"’

And after fixing that error, this code:

```
dbClearResult(p1)
```

Produces this warning:

> unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbClearResult’ for signature ‘"data.frame"’

Can somebody please explain what this type of error message is trying to tell me?

Specifically, the terms "interhited", "method", "function", and "signature" all seem related to concepts I understand from other languages, but the sentence structure of this error implies they have slightly different meanings in R.

Comment: You should definitely include the code that generated this error.

Comment: There have been several pieces of code that generated similar errors, I'm not looking for specific solutions, but an explanation of this class of error.

Comment: So pick one and include it in your question. The error may arise from different circumstances, but you should provide a specific, reproducible example as a basis to your question.

Comment: @nrussell updated, to include examples

Comment: It looks like the `dbConnect` function requires a DBIDriver object and not a character string (I think the documentation is wrong). See the examples on `?dbConnect`. And `dbClearResult` should be used on the return value from `dbSendQuery`, not `fetch()`. Basically in both cases you are just passing an object of the wrong type to the function.

Comment: Yup, IIRC @MrFlick is spot on, and that documentation is misleading. I think you need to do something more like this: `mydrv <- dbDriver("SQLite"); con <- dbConnect(drv=mydrv, ...)`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

That is the type of message you will get when attempting to apply an S4 generic function to an object of a class for which  no defined S4 method exists (or at least has been attached to the current R session).

Here's an example using the **raster** package (for spatial raster data), which is chock full of S4 functions.

```
library(raster)

## raster::rotate() is an S4 function with just one method, for "Raster" class objects
isS4(rotate)
# [1] TRUE
showMethods(rotate)
# Function: rotate (package raster)
# x="Raster"

## Lets see what happens when we pass it an object that's *not* of class "Raster"
x <- 1:10
class(x)
# [1] "integer"
rotate(x)
# Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
#   unable to find an inherited method for function ‘rotate’ for signature ‘"integer"’
```

Comment: @JoshObrien Thanks! And S4 is is R's type system? And the error from applying `rotate` to `x` would be fixed (for example) by change the type of `x` to some type on which `rotate` was defined?

Comment: @user12341234 To your first question, it's actually more complicated than that. S4 is *one* of R's object oriented class systems. S3 is the most commonly used, with S4 probably next most frequently used. [See here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html) or perhaps [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S4.html) for more. And yes, the only way to fix the error in from applying `rotate()` to `x` would be to make sure that `x` is an object of class `"Raster"`.

Comment: @JoshObrien Thanks, I appreciate the help.

Comment: Even if outdated, just wanted to say thanks Josh for providing this answer! Never troubleshooted a problem this quickly, even if I still dont fully comprehend why this pkg caused it. A ```data.table::shift``` operation broke in my code after I changed many small bits here and there and never suspected this library to be the culprit!

Answer (score 15):

I have seen this message numerous times, as a result of namespace conflicts.

Here is a MRE: Both the `hash` and `data.table` libraries have `copy` functions.

In a new `R` session:

```
> library(data.table)
> library(hash)
```

causes `copy` from `data.table` to be masked:

```
> DT = data.table(x=rep(c("b","a","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9)
> copy(DT)
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘copy’ for signature ‘"data.table"’
```

*The solution is to specify the namespace*:

```
> data.table::copy(DT)
   x y v
1: b 1 1
2: b 3 2
3: b 6 3
4: a 1 4
5: a 3 5
6: a 6 6
7: c 1 7
8: c 3 8
9: c 6 9
```