# mas5 normalization error: unable to find an inherited method for function

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

**Goal**: `mas5` normalize data.

**Problem**: when I try the following R code, I get this

```
error: unable to find an inherited method for function bg.correct for signature ExpressionFeatureSet, character
```

I have looked on SO, and found the following: [What does this mean: unable to find an inherited method for function ‘A’ for signature ‘"B"’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36943201/what-does-this-mean-unable-to-find-an-inherited-method-for-function-a-for-sig), but I am not exactly sure how to fix my specific problem and use the `mas5` function properly. I have also looked at this [affy manual](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/manuals/affy/man/affy.pdf) but still stuck...

```
installpkg("affy")
library('affy')
setwd("/Users/er/Desktop/DesktopFolders/DataSets/CD8Helios/Microarray/CELfiles/CEL")
cel_Files <- list.celfiles()
affyRaw <- read.celfiles(cel_Files)
eset <- mas5(affyRaw)
```

Comment: As the error suggests, it seems that an `ExpressionFeatureSet` is being given as input and no signature is available to run the function on this class of object.  The `mas5()` function states that an object inheriting from `AffyBatch` must be given as input (http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/manuals/affy/man/affy.pdf).    `ExpressionFeatureSet` does not inherit from `AffyBatch`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that the `.cel` files were created based on experiments performed on the type of array that works with `affy` package than you should try this workflow using `ReadAffy` from `affy` package.

```
cel_Files <- list.celfiles()
affyRaw <- affy::ReadAffy(filenames=cel_Files)
eset <- mas5(affyRaw)
```

However, it might be the case that the `affy` package is not designed for your array type. Then, you should switch to the `oligo` and `oligoClasses` packages and normalize with analogous function `rma`

```
 cel_Files <-  oligoClasses::list.celfiles()
 affyRaw <- oligo::read.celfiles(cel_Files)
 eset <- oligo::rma(affyRaw)
```