# SparkR distinct (on databricks)

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I am new to SparkR, so please forgive if my question is very basic.

I work on databricks and try to get all unique dates of a column of a SparkDataFrame.

When I run:

```
uniquedays <- SparkR::distinct(df$datadate)
```

I get the error message:

```
unable to find an inherited method for function ‘distinct’ for signature ‘"Column"’
```

On [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36943201/what-does-this-mean-unable-to-find-an-inherited-method-for-function-a-for-sig), I found out that this usually means 
(If I run isS4(df), it returns TRUE):

> That is the type of message you will get when attempting to apply an S4 generic function to an object of a class for which no defined S4 method exists

I also tried to run

```
uniquedays <- SparkR::unique(df$datadate)
```

where I get the error message:

```
unique() applies only to vectors
```

It feels like, I am missing something basic here. 
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(magrittr)
uniquedays <- SparkR::select(df, df$datadate) %>% SparkR::distinct()
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Do you have an intuitive explanaition why this code works, while mine does not?

Comment: Not really, I'm still learning spark as well. What I do know is that Spark is a distributed SQL language. Whenever I get weird errors for things I normally do without thought in R, (i.e. unique(df$blah) ) I take a step back and make sure I am fully specifying the source data for my function. A lot of the time this just means adding a select(df, df$blah) %>% and then the code I really just wanted to run. This is really helpful for whenever the source documentation for the function is for a "signature dataframe" https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/api/R/unique.html