# R linux terminal execution of gWidget script

Tags: r, linux, terminal, gwidgets

I've written a script in R using the gWidgets library. It  works perfectly when I copy and paste the script into R, but it's failing mid-execution when executed using

```
./myscript.r
```

in the linux terminal with an error message

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
>     unable to find an inherited method for function ‘.gwindow’ for signature ‘"NULL"’
>   Calls: gwindow -> .gwindow ->

I used the gwindow function once in the script as this:`

```
win <- gwindow("Diary", horizontal = FALSE, visible=TRUE, height = 1000)
```

So, I'm asking, why do I have an error message for 'signature "NULL"' ?

Comment: Please read [SO: What does this mean: unable to find an inherited method for function ‘A’ for signature ‘“B”’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36943201/what-does-this-mean-unable-to-find-an-inherited-method-for-function-a-for-sig)

Comment: On reading the above link, it seems that the solution should be to force the object to be a class in the library gWidgets with this code win1 <- gwindow("Diary", horizontal = FALSE, visible=TRUE, height = 1000, class="gWidgets") but on testing this behaves exactly as before.

Comment: After more testing, I've found that I can make the error appear for a different function if I insert an argument specifiying the toolkit

Comment: If there is something to change gWidgets side, please post here @curly.

Comment: hi @jverzani , if I change the code to this  `win <- gwindow(title="Diary", horizontal = FALSE, visible=TRUE, height = 1000, toolkit = guiToolkit("RGtk2")) ` the error message focuses on the function ggroup().   I applied the same solution to each group() function, with all the of libraries used in the code 
library(RGtk2)
library(cairoDevice)
library(gWidgets)
library(gWidgetsRGtk2) but it didn't work for ggroup()

Comment: Do you get the same error with gWidgets2? (I’d re ommend that either way)

Comment: I replaced `library(gWidgets)` with library(gWidgets2), with all the permutations cited above. Same result; It works perfectly when pasted into R, but running it from Terminal with ./myscript.r fails.  I noticed that running it in R that there was the following message: see next comment

Comment: The following objects are masked from ‘package:gWidgets2’:

    add, addDropSource, addDropTarget, addHandler, addHandlerBlur,
    addHandlerChanged, 
    .gbasicdialog, gbutton, .gbutton, gcalendar, .gcalendar, gcheckbox,
    .gcheckbox, gcheckboxgroup, .gcheckboxgroup, gcombobox, gconfirm,
  [...]
    .gfilebrowse, gformlayout, .gformlayout, gframe, .gframe,
    ggraphics, .ggraphics, ggraphicsnotebook, .ggraphicsnotebook,
    ggroup, .ggroup, ghtml, .ghtml, gimage, .gimage, ginput, .ginput,