# Why does function: Score return error: unable to find an inherited method for function ‘score’ for signature ‘"bn"’

Tags: r, bayesian-networks, bnlearn

I want to show the score for a Bayesian network.

I'm not yet experienced in correcting errors that occur, so I hope that someone here knows how to solve it.

Here is the code I'm running:

```
library(bnlearn)
library(Rgraphviz)
library(gRain)
library(graph)
library(grid)
library(snow)

data("learning.test")
bn.AB <- gs(learning.test, blacklist = c("B", "A"))
score(bn.AB, learning.test, type = "bde")
```

The result should say: -24002.36

This is the error that is produced:

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
> unable to find an inherited method for function ‘score’ for signature ‘"bn"’

It seems to be a problem related to the `score` function, from the `bnlearn` package, asking for object of S4 form, but "bn" being S3.

This is the post that pointed in that direction:
[What does this mean: unable to find an inherited method for function ‘A’ for signature ‘"B"’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36943201/what-does-this-mean-unable-to-find-an-inherited-method-for-function-a-for-sig)

I hope someone will assist in solving it.

Comment: Likely, you have another (loaded) package with a `score()` function. Try with `bnlearn::score()` to make sure you use the one from `bnlearn`.

Comment: Please include your `library()` statements that go with the code above in the code you are sharing here.

Comment: Almost certainly you need to reverse the order in which you load `Rgraphviz` and `bnlearn`, otherwise use the namespace as meriops suggests

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. Using bnlearn::score solved it.