# GDCprepare() returns Error in function (classes, fdef, mtable)

Tags: r, bioconductor

I have downloaded Proteome Profiling data from the TCGA-LGG project with the Bioconductor package `TCGAbiolinks`.
Then I have the following error when running `GDCprepare`:

```r
library("TCGAbiolinks")
query_lgg = GDCquery(
  project = "TCGA-LGG",
  data.category = "Proteome Profiling",
  sample.type = "Primary Tumor", 
  legacy = FALSE)
#> --------------------------------------
#> o GDCquery: Searching in GDC database
#> --------------------------------------
#> Genome of reference: hg38
#> --------------------------------------------
#> oo Accessing GDC. This might take a while...
#> --------------------------------------------
#> ooo Project: TCGA-LGG
#> --------------------
#> oo Filtering results
#> --------------------
#> ooo By sample.type
#> ----------------
#> oo Checking data
#> ----------------
#> ooo Check if there are duplicated cases
#> ooo Check if there results for the query
#> -------------------
#> o Preparing output
#> -------------------

lgg_res <- getResults(query_lgg) 

GDCdownload(query = query_lgg)
#> Downloading data for project TCGA-LGG
#> Of the 429 files for download 429 already exist.
#> All samples have been already downloaded

lgg_data <- GDCprepare(query_lgg)
#> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited method for function 'metadata<-' for signature '"function"'
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Session info

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> ─ Session info  ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value
#>  version  R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
#>  os       Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
#>  system   x86_64, linux-gnu
#>  ui       X11
#>  language (EN)
#>  collate  it_IT.UTF-8
#>  ctype    it_IT.UTF-8
#>  tz       Europe/Rome
#>  date     2021-11-10
#>  pandoc   2.11.4 @ /usr/lib/rstudio/bin/pandoc/ (via rmarkdown)
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package              * version  date (UTC) lib source
#>  AnnotationDbi          1.54.1   2021-06-08 [1] Bioconductor
#>  assertthat             0.2.1    2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  backports              1.3.0    2021-10-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  Biobase                2.52.0   2021-05-19 [1] Bioconductor
#>  BiocFileCache          2.0.0    2021-05-19 [1] Bioconductor
#>  BiocGenerics           0.38.0   2021-05-19 [1] Bioconductor
#>  biomaRt                2.48.3   2021-08-15 [1] Bioconductor
#>  Biostrings             2.60.2   2021-08-05 [1] Bioconductor
#>  bit                    4.0.4    2020-08-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  bit64                  4.0.5    2020-08-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  bitops                 1.0-7    2021-04-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  blob                   1.2.2    2021-07-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  cachem                 1.0.6    2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  cli                    3.1.0    2021-10-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  colorspace             2.0-2    2021-06-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  crayon                 1.4.2    2021-10-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  curl                   4.3.2    2021-06-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  data.table             1.14.2   2021-09-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  DBI                    1.1.1    2021-01-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  dbplyr                 2.1.1    2021-04-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  DelayedArray           0.18.0   2021-05-19 [1] Bioconductor
#>  digest                 0.6.28   2021-09-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  downloader             0.4      2015-07-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  dplyr                  1.0.7    2021-06-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  ellipsis               0.3.2    2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  evaluate               0.14     2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  fansi                  0.5.0    2021-05-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  fastmap                1.1.0    2021-01-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  filelock               1.0.2    2018-10-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  fs                     1.5.0    2020-07-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  generics               0.1.1    2021-10-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  GenomeInfoDb           1.28.4   2021-09-05 [1] Bioconductor
#>  GenomeInfoDbData       1.2.6    2021-11-10 [1] Bioconductor
#>  GenomicRanges          1.44.0   2021-05-19 [1] Bioconductor
#>  ggplot2                3.3.5    2021-06-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  glue                   1.5.0    2021-11-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  gtable                 0.3.0    2019-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  highr                  0.9      2021-04-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  hms                    1.1.1    2021-09-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  htmltools              0.5.2    2021-08-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  httr                   1.4.2    2020-07-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  IRanges                2.26.0   2021-05-19 [1] Bioconductor
#>  jsonlite               1.7.2    2020-12-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  KEGGREST               1.32.0   2021-05-19 [1] Bioconductor
#>  knitr                  1.36     2021-09-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  lattice                0.20-44  2021-05-02 [4] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  lifecycle              1.0.1    2021-09-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  magrittr               2.0.1    2020-11-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  Matrix                 1.3-4    2021-06-01 [4] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  MatrixGenerics         1.4.3    2021-08-26 [1] Bioconductor
#>  matrixStats            0.61.0   2021-09-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  memoise                2.0.0    2021-01-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  munsell                0.5.0    2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  pillar                 1.6.4    2021-10-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  pkgconfig              2.0.3    2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  plyr                   1.8.6    2020-03-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  png                    0.1-7    2013-12-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  prettyunits            1.1.1    2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  progress               1.2.2    2019-05-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  purrr                  0.3.4    2020-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  R.cache                0.15.0   2021-04-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  R.methodsS3            1.8.1    2020-08-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  R.oo                   1.24.0   2020-08-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  R.utils                2.11.0   2021-09-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  R6                     2.5.1    2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  rappdirs               0.3.3    2021-01-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  Rcpp                   1.0.7    2021-07-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  RCurl                  1.98-1.5 2021-09-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  readr                  2.0.2    2021-09-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  reprex                 2.0.1    2021-08-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  rlang                  0.4.12   2021-10-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  rmarkdown              2.11     2021-09-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  RSQLite                2.2.8    2021-08-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  rstudioapi             0.13     2020-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  rvest                  1.0.2    2021-10-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  S4Vectors              0.30.2   2021-10-03 [1] Bioconductor
#>  scales                 1.1.1    2020-05-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  sessioninfo            1.2.1    2021-11-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  stringi                1.7.5    2021-10-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  stringr                1.4.0    2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  styler                 1.6.2    2021-09-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  SummarizedExperiment   1.22.0   2021-05-19 [1] Bioconductor
#>  TCGAbiolinks         * 2.20.1   2021-10-07 [1] Bioconductor
#>  TCGAbiolinksGUI.data   1.12.0   2021-05-20 [1] Bioconductor
#>  tibble                 3.1.6    2021-11-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  tidyr                  1.1.4    2021-09-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  tidyselect             1.1.1    2021-04-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  tzdb                   0.2.0    2021-10-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  utf8                   1.2.2    2021-07-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  vctrs                  0.3.8    2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  withr                  2.4.2    2021-04-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  xfun                   0.28     2021-11-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  XML                    3.99-0.8 2021-09-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  xml2                   1.3.2    2020-04-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  XVector                0.32.0   2021-05-19 [1] Bioconductor
#>  yaml                   2.2.1    2020-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  zlibbioc               1.38.0   2021-05-19 [1] Bioconductor
#> 
#>  [1] /home/matt/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1
#>  [2] /usr/local/lib/R/site-library
#>  [3] /usr/lib/R/site-library
#>  [4] /usr/lib/R/library
#> 
#> ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

I tried to investigate the error and it lead me to Issue [#198](https://github.com/BioinformaticsFMRP/TCGAbiolinks/issues/198), but with no success.

Also, I understand that this error is related to S4 generic function being applied to an object with no defined S4 method, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36943411/5093502).

Am I missing something? Can somebody please help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for proteome profiling has been provided in the package. To obtain the newest version the package should be installed from Github with the following command `BiocManager::install("BioinformaticsFMRP/TCGAbiolinks")` ([see here](https://github.com/BioinformaticsFMRP/TCGAbiolinks/issues/478)).