# Why use of pool::dbGetQuery with lapply isn't working?

Tags: r, pool, r-dbi

I'm trying to use R's "pool" package to execute a set of queries against a set of databases.

I have a list of queries, `queryList` (I confirmed that each element is a character vector, e.g. "SELECT...FROM...").

```
library(pool)
library(DBI)

# queryList defined earlier

myPool <- dbPool (...)

Results <- lapply(queryList, pool::dbGetQuery, myPool)  # fails here!
```

The error I get says this:  "unable to find an inherited method for function 'dbGetQuery' for signature '"character", "Pool"'.

One [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36943201/what-does-this-mean-unable-to-find-an-inherited-method-for-function-a-for-sig) says this is related to S4 incompatibility.  `pool::dbGetQuery` is an S4 method.

Is there a workaround ?

Comment: I'm not sure that `lapply` is being used correctly in your code. `dbGetQuery()` takes the connection as first argument and a query as the second. So maybe something like: `lapply(queryList, function(x) dbGetQuery(myPool, x))` would work? It's also not clear from your code how query results are assigned to a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of an anonymous function (e.g. `function(x)...`, as suggested by @neilfws) worked.  However, I'm not sure why, since I didn't need to use anonymous functions when I was dealing directly with dbiConnection objects. So this works

```
lapply(queryList, DBI::dbGetQuery, conn) # conn is dbiConnection
```

but this doesn't work

```
lapply(queryList, pool::dbGetQuery, pool) # pool is a pool of dbiConnections
```

Maybe I'm misreading the official documentation?